# Row number in query result

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have query to get firms by theirs sales last year.

```
select
   Name,
   Sale
from Sales
order by
   Sale DESC
```

and I get

```
Firm 2 | 200 000
Firm 1 | 190 000
Firm 3 | 100 000
```

And I would like to get index of row in result. For `Firm 2` I would like to get `0` (or `1`), for `Firm 3` `1` (or `2`) and etc. Is this possible? Or at least create some sort of autoincrement column. I can use even stored procedure if it is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebird 3.0 supports `row_number()` which is the better way to do this.

However for Firebird 2.5, you can get what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.Name, s.Sale,
       (select count(*) from Sales s2 where s2.sale >= s.sale) as seqnum
from Sales s
order by s.Sale DESC;
```

Comment: @Sk1X1 . . . That's why I suggest a correlated subquery.

Comment: My mistake, sorry... At the end, great solution, thanks a lot! :-)