# Generating row number without ordering any column

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

I want to generate row numbers in the same order the data are added.
The below query is working fine for SQL Server.

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO FROM TestTable
```

I need standard query to achieve the same scenario in Firebird. Can anyone suggest me about this?

Comment: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq343/

Comment: try just removing `OVER(....)` clause. Or try `OVER( ORDER BY 1 )` https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323982/row-number-in-query-result

Comment: this suggests Firebird 3 can have empty OVER clause: `SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () SNO FROM TestTable` - see http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/row-number-window-function-with-over-td4633750.html - however the Window Functions that you use in YOUR example query were introduced in SQL 2003 AFAIR, not SQL 92

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row number in query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323982/row-number-in-query-result)

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? The query as shown should work with Firebird 3.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no it should not - `(SELECT 100)` part should fail. And the requirement is for some weird reason ANSI SQL 92, not even Firebird itself. Go figure...

Comment: @Arioch'The: As per your suggestions, I tried the query like " SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS SNO FROM Orders ". It works fine for firebird. But the same is fail for SQL server. I need standard (ANSI SQL standard) query for both cases. Is it possible? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Can't you just use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`? That should work in both, and is defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: @Arioch'The I had failed to notice the absence of a table there.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Yes. Specified syntax is not work in sql. I got this error =>  "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `row_number() over (order by (select 100))` with Firebird, because Firebird - as required by the SQL standard - requires a `from` clause for a `select`. The equivalent in Firebird would be `row_number() over (order by (select 100 from rdb$database))`.

The best solution would be to use an actual column for the `order by` to ensure a deterministic order.

When looking at the SQL:2016 standard, then an `order by` is not required for `row_number()` (but it is for `rank()` and `dense_rank()`). Unfortunately, it looks like Microsoft applied that requirement for `row_number()` as well, possibly for uniformity with the rank-functions, and maybe because `row_number()` without an order does not make a lot of sense. Using `row_number() over ()` with SQL Server yields an error *"The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."*, but works with Firebird.

SQL Server also enforces that the order by in a window function is not a numeric column reference. Using `row_number() over (order by 1)` with SQL Server yields an error *"Windowed functions, aggregates and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions."*, but works with Firebird (although the `1` is taken as a literal 1, and not as column reference, contrary to an `order by` on select level).

SQL Server also does not support using constants or literals in the order by in a window function. Using `row_number() over (order by '1')` with SQL Server yields an error *"Windowed functions, aggregates and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions."*, but works with Firebird.

I did find a trick that worked for both Firebird 3 and SQL Server 2017, but it is a dirty hack:

```
row_number() over (order by current_user)
```

This works because SQL Server doesn't consider `current_user` as a constant, but as a function, which means it doesn't fall under the 'no constants allowed'-rule.

Be aware that this trick may yield inconsistent row numbers (eg in Firebird multiple window functions evaluated with different constants will yield different values, and the window function is evaluated before an `order by` on select level), and you may want to consider if you shouldn't simply track a row index in your application.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be usage of `ORDER BY RAND()`:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(i INT);
INSERT INTO TestTable(i) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO TestTable(i) VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO TestTable(i) VALUES (30);

SELECT TestTable.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS SNO 
FROM TestTable;
```

[db<>fiddle demo - Firebird](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=2147c05f36973d0c3ed7846d8477f5e1)

[db<>fiddle demo - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=2147c05f36973d0c3ed7846d8477f5e1)